# How did I mess up python pdb

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

previously, I had pdb installed system-wide using `pip install`, a little after I found out about `ipdb`. successfully installed it with pip.
Didn't quite work well, made me decided to go back to former pdb.
Now I get error using `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

> exceptions.AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_trace'

Any idea what is going wrong?

EDIT:
this is the error after re-installing IPython and PDB back again:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/debugger.py", line 59, in 
>       from pdb import Pdb as OldPdb
>   ImportError: cannot import name Pdb

Comment: please provide few information about which OS your using and weather you to try to remove some pkgs using pip and you installed python dev tools ?

Comment: @snehalparmar I'm on Ubuntu Linux 14.04, I tried installing pdb and ipdb with pip. Then removed them using pip again. I'm not sure what got messed up!

Comment: Is there another file in your working directory named `pdb.py`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem. Apparently there's another module in pip repository called `pdb` for shared password management. each time attempting `pip install pdb` I did not know my machine was installing the wrong module. 
`pdb` module(python debugger) is shipped with product when you install it on your system or in the case of Linux Ubuntu, it is included in the distribution which are located at `/usr/lib/python2.7` as opposed to the third party modules that get installed under `/usr/local/lib/python2.7`. 
For some weird, unknown reason(I guess installing ipdb caused that), I did not have the pdb.py under my pre-shipped python modules. e.g, `/usr/lib/python2.7`. 
what fixed my problem was downloading the pdb.py module from the python documentation website and located that file within the mentioned folder. 
Hope this could help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes I met same issue today and solution is same as above, try analyze by typing `pip freeze | grep pdb` and you may see:

```
ipdb==0.9.0

pdb==0.1
```

This means you have installed pdb yourself and this covered ipdb, after pip uninstall pdb, you should only keep

```
ipdb==0.9.0
```

Remaining!

Answer (score 2):

try following cmd and check weather there is pdb in list or not:

```
pip freeze
```

There will be an list of all the pkgs installed with python check here,

also if you try this :

```
 pip uninstall pdb
 Cannot uninstall requirement pdb, not installed
 Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpVgAfBP
```

can you confirm the output of :

```
 pip uninstall pdb
```

Comment: Well, I have done this already! I re-installed it back again using pip; this time when I'm importing pdb, running any python object I get the error that set_trace() function does't exist in the module.

Comment: if you dont have any issue try installing python again, your system might be having two copy of pdb and not able to import it properly.

Comment: That's what I figured! how would I go about unistalling pdb other that `pip uninstall`?

Comment: I try to re-create the issue on my machine but can't do. Thats why i want to know how know how did you uninstall pdb, as its python internal pkg and not installed using pip, so it cant be uninstall from pip. Please provide me some points by which i could hep dude.

Comment: I figured what the problem was. I will post it as an answer.